# Failed to find byte code for com/google/firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, bytecode

I made following upgrades today

1. Android Studio **3.0** -> **3.1**
2. In `build.gradle`

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.0.1**' -> **3.1.0**
   }
3. In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-4.5-all.zip** -> **gradle-4.6-all.zip**

And I am now getting following error with my firebase modules (random module at a time when I build)

> Failed to find byte code for
>   com/google/firebase/storage/StreamDownloadTask$StreamProcessor

or sometimes

> Failed to find byte code for
>   com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener

My project implements

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is addressed in the latest react-native-firebase v4 release candidate, available here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/releases/tag/v4.0.0-rc.3

The fix was ultimately to update the react-native-firebase build.gradle to use `compileOnly` instead of `compile` statements.

Comment: I faced the same problem resolved by disabling instance run in android studio settings.

Comment: I've open the firebase-build.gradle file, but there are compileOnly everywhere in this file. So only solution from Bhavdip Sagar to disable "instance run" on Android Studio.

Comment: Why do i still this issue then:  "react-native-firebase": "^4.0.6",

Answer (score 23):

I have the same error

> Failed to find byte code for com/google/firebase/database/Transaction$Handler

(although i don't use `firebase/database`).

Have found that disabling instant run in AndroidStudio settings resolve this issue.

Comment:  This potentially saves me hours of time.  It is September 2018 now. It is puzzling that Google has not solved this bug of Android Studio.

Comment: This saves me a few hours, this is not the first time for me to get Android Studio work by disabling Instant Run

Comment: You superhero! One day wasted on this and similar stuff, but it could have been much more!!

Comment: This answer also helps me. I am new to android studio, If anyone knows how to disable instant run in AndroidStudio then follow this link [https://developer.android.com/studio/run#disable-ir] or you can follow this steps To disable Instant Run:
1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

Answer (score 2):

In the dependencies add:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

to be able to use `ChildEventListener` and `StreamDownloadTask$StreamProcessor`

Also you may have to write the other firebase dependencies

Comment: Yep, had to add few more

Comment: @Ilja I had to add all Firebase dependencies (like 15) in order for the project to build, while I am only interested in 3 of them. This doesn't seem right

Comment: @Peter Haddad The exact same thing Ilja reported but for different packages. For example: 'Failed to find byte code for com/google/firebase/storage/OnPausedListener', this disappeared when adding the storage dependency. I'm not using Firebase for storage whatsoever.

Comment: @Sammekl its similar with me, I had to add all firebase modules I was not using

Comment: @PeterHaddad Maybe its worth to alter the answer saying that one will need to include all packages needed for firebase for project to compile

Comment: Same behaviour occurs with v 12.0.0 of everything

Comment: @Sammekl are you using `react-native-firebase` by any chance?

Comment: @Ilja Yes I am! version 3.3.0

Comment: @Sammekl Could you add your input to this issue: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/915

Comment: @Ilja No need I think, see it's already fixed in 4.0. Will try that one, thanks :)